# What RESTful data source (service) use for Ember.js RESTAdapter for MySQL database on PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ember.js

I have a server with PHP support and a MySQL database. Ember.js supports RestAdapter that takes a url to a rest service.

So my question is what is the simplest solution to expose my database as a rest service for Ember.js?

My database is in MySQL and i have PHP support.

Comment: Do you use some web framework, like zend etc. I don't code in php, but I think that this is a usefull info.

Comment: well... if some framework is helpful than i can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cakephp. I used that framework back in my PHP days and it works pretty well. I also found [this](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html) mini guide on exposing RESTful api endpoints in cake.

If you're using ember data, it is somewhat specific about how the json payload should look, so just bear that in mind.

Comment: It looks lice, but it's not more helpful than writing in pure PHP. I would need something that does more.